# Swing JTabbedPane : addChangeListener or addContainerListener or both?

Tags: swing, exception, listener, jtabbedpane, swingworker

I have one swing code written by other person. For swing tabbed pane, he has added both change and container listener and both calls the same method:

```
addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent theEvent ) {
    someMethod();
    }
} );

addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter() {
  public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent theEvent) {
    someMethod();
  }
  public void componentRemoved(ContainerEvent theEvent) {
    someMethod();
  }
} );
```

Whenever tab is removed from this tabbed pane, it internally calls JTabbedPane.removeTabAt(int index), which in turn calls fireStateChanged() causing new change event listened by change listener.
Now as new component (tab) is removed from tabbed pane, it also calls componentRemoved(ContainerEvent theEvent) method of container listener.

Both change even and container events, then calls same method someMethod(), which does set background and foreground colors.

I would like to know, if this kind code might cause some issues. Recently we are facing random IndexOutOfBoundException exeptions. I am just wondering, if this is causing this issue.

Also as per my understanding in swing, once event is listened, logic inside it should be executed using worker thread (e.g. SwingWorker). Please let me know if this is correct.

I am new to swing, thus any hint would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever tab is removed from this tabbed pane, it internally calls
>   JTabbedPane.removeTabAt(int index), which in turn calls
>   fireStateChanged() causing new change event listened by change
>   listener.

This is true if the removed tab is also the selected tab. In the other cases, you won't be notified.

You need to choose what event you want to listen to:

- Addition/Removal of components?--> go for `ContainerListener`
- Selected tab? --> go for `ChangeListener`

> I would like to know, if this kind code might cause some issues.
>   Recently we are facing random IndexOutOfBoundException exeptions. I am
>   just wondering, if this is causing this issue.

Since there is no line in your sample code that could throw that Exception, it is impossible to answer your question. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that shows your issue.

> Also as per my understanding in swing, once event is listened, logic
>   inside it should be executed using worker thread (e.g. SwingWorker).
>   Please let me know if this is correct.

It depends:

- If you need to modify anything in the UI, anything related to Swing, it needs to be executed on the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) and thus, `SwingWorker` is not an option.
- If you need to perform business logic operations, and especially if they can be lengthy, then you should indeed use a `SwingWorker` or any other mechanism to execute that code in another thread than the EDT. Consider visiting the `Swing` tag wiki on "Concurrency"